# Complicated Cron expression

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net, crontrigger

Can I use cron to solve the following very specific use case?

I want the scheduler to fire every five minutes from a specific startTime like "13:00h" to "17:45h".

I've tried something that comes very close to this, which is

```
0 0-45/5 13-17 ? * *
```

The problem with this is, that the scheduler doesn't fire between xx:45 and xx:59 each hour.

How can I solve this so that the scheduler fires every 5 minutes from the startTime (13h) until the endTime (17:45h).

Thank in advance for your help. I already basically looked everywhere online but couldn't find anything.

Best Regards Simon

Comment: So why do you tag your question with `c#` and `quartz.net` if you asking about cron?

Comment: because i use the crontrigger in quartz.net and i thought maybe the cron used in quartz could be different from other versions of cron. (kind of like regex is on different regex engines), so I thought I'd add it for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you'll need two entries.

Have you tried:-

```
*/5 13-16 * * *
0-45/5 17 * * *
```

You can test them here:-

http://cron.schlitt.info/

Comment: no but that is also not what I want it to do. This statement fires every 5 minutes from 13 to 18h I want it to stop at 17:45. (see above)

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks, so I definitely need two statements. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this site to parse cron expressions online.
http://cron.qqe2.com/